# Adjust image to div and centering it

Tags: css, image, html

well, I have a div holder with dimensions width:200px and height:110px.

When i load an image, normally it exceeds such dimensions, so i need to adjust the image to such content by width or height depending of the dimensions of the image. So, if its adjusted by with, three situations may occur:

1.- height is higher than 110px, so as the div overflow is set to hidden, it will need to center it vertically.

2.- height is equal than 110px, no problem.

3.- (**The issue**) height is less than 110px. What's suponed i should do in this situation? because I want to cover all the div content.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you load the image as a background for the container, you can mess around with `background-size: cover` or `background-size: contain` and use `background-position: center center` to keep it in the middle regardless of size.

Alternatively, you might want to use a table cell, as these allow contents to be vertically aligned inside (either use a table with one cell, or `display: table-cell` on the container).

Comment: Incredible!!! Exactly what is was expecting... many thanks. I used back-ground-size:cover, because 'contain' did not work properly, and not used display: table-cell. it was not necessary, but if you think that for any reason, please feed me back.